# Show that the given function is R-Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Show that the function $f(x)=[x^2]+|x-1|$ is Riemann Integrable on $[0,2]$ where $[\alpha]$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $\alpha$

Defining the function over the interval i get

$$f(x)=1-x , 0\le x<1$$ and $$f(x)=x,1\le x<2$$
But this gives that the function is not continuous in the closed interval. How can it R-Integrable ?

Answer (score 0):

A function with a finite number of discontinuities is Riemann integrable.

Comment: is continuity not a necessary condition ?

Comment: @AmanMittal No, it is a sufficient condition.

Comment: A bounded function is Riemann integrable iff its set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way. In calculating the Riemann integral, you are allowed to choose whatever subdivision of the domain you want, so long as you take subdivisions that are increasingly fine and corresponding Riemann sums have a limit.

Now, if a function is bounded and only has one point of discontinuity, let's show it's integrable.  You can take your subdivisions so no interval straddles that point of discontinuity; the Riemann sum for the whole domain is the same as the sum of the Riemann sums for each "half" of the domain.  You know the Riemann sums on each half of the domain converge, because the function is bounded and continuous on each half of the domain; so the Riemann sums on the whole domain converge as well, and the function is Riemann integrable.

By induction, any bounded function with finitely many points of discontinuity is Riemann integrable.